# What is the proper Django Project/App Structure

Tags: django

New to Django, new to Python.  Moving from Symfony/PHP and MVC/C# just because it's something different.

So I'm starting an App, this app will not be used as a piece of any other app.  Following along in the tutorial it almost seems like Django wants me to put each url as it's on App.  For example:

```
/directors
/ledgers
```

The reason I say it seems like Django wants me to use an App per url family is because in the tutorial the views/models/templates are in the App, and use use index.html/details.html, etc, like so

```
polls --> templates --> index.html
                        details.html
```

Whereas in Symfony for example, in the templates I'd be able to branch to other folders like so.

```
views --> directors --> index.html
                        details.html
          ledgers   --> index.html
                        details.html
```

For Django  how would I handle the same scenerio?  Just name each template different?  For example:

```
polls --> templates --> directors_index.html
                        directors_details.html
                        ledgers_index.html
                        ledgers_details.html
```

Or would I move each to their own App?  Very confused.

Comment: You can create per-app subdirectories inside the template folder, akin to how symfony does it.

Comment: Ok, so that means it's perfectly acceptable to have one app in a project and everything in that app.

Comment: Yes, you can put everything in one app if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Talk is cheap , why not let me just show you a picture.
[image]