# Multiple App directories in the project folder

Tags: django

Dears, I was following the Django official tutorial to build a poll app. However, as I was learning, I tried to create other apps to practice some aspects of Django. In the end, my directory looks like this. Is it correct to organize directories this way? It seems to me that APP polls, generic_practice, practice are sharing the settings.py, urls.py, the database,etc. Any recommended reading material about organizing multiple apps in one project?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper Django Project/App Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573568/what-is-the-proper-django-project-app-structure)

Comment: There's a lot of reading available to guide you through it. e. g: [Best practice for Django project working directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23469321/7303434)

Answer (score 0):

Except your template folder,  everything is okay. If you are using BASE_DIR as 'templates', then the template folder should be inside mysite folder. Easy to remember, every folder associated with your command python manage.py should be inside the folder where manage.py stays.